# Error: cannot call methods on spinner prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disableWithoutRemovingValue'

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I tried to use the ui.spinner.js plugin, and in document ready i initialize some textbox to be a disabled spinner like this:

```
$('#id').spinner("disableWithoutRemovingValue");
```

In this case is have this error :
Error: cannot call methods on spinner prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disableWithoutRemovingValue'. Also, i tried to change disableWithoutRemovingValue by using option but still i have the same error.
So, is there any one help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with same trouble and I've found the workaround is resolving that:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    $('#id').spinner("disableWithoutRemovingValue");
});
```